# Can a number with $100$ $0$'s $100$ $1$'s and $100$ $2$'s ever be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory

Can a number with $100$ $0$'s $100$ $1$'s and $100$ $2$'s ever be a perfect square? I have no idea where to even start. Some hints would be nice. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I managed to solve the question

Answer (score 4):

Hint: consider divisibility by - well I'll let you think which numbers would be easy to test using the information you have been given.

Answer (score 1):

First we see that the figures of the number add up to 300.

Then we see that therefore the number is divisible by 3 and not by 9.

For it to be a square you would need it to be multiple of 9 since it is multiple 3.